# Tag for articy:draft?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently I found this software called articy:draft, and I fell in love with it. It's a pretty neat software that allows you to organize your story (for a video game) in a visual way. Since Writer (or Writing now, I guess) features a tag specifically for video games and writing software like Scrivener, I thought it would be nice to have a tag just for this software, in case someone needs help or advice.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is the software widely used in the relevant community? (I have no idea if it is or not, hence the question!) I'm not sure it makes sense to have a tag for every single software package, but if it's widely used, then it might very well make sense.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling To be honest, I'm not quite sure either, but it doesn't seem like it's widely used (yet). It's been out there for a while I think, but I only recently found out about it, and after using it, I'm still wondering why nobody really talks about it much. My only guess is the high price tag puts a lot of people off, but it's so good that I think it justifies the cost.

Answer (score 5):

As there is precedent with [scrivener](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrivener), shown in [this meta discussion](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266/creating-a-new-tag) I would say that the creation of a tag is okay. There is also a specialised tag for [microsoft-word](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word), too. See also [A broad guideline for questions about writing-specific software](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1101/23159).

**But tags should only created when they are needed.**

Creating tags just because someone at some point may ask a question about some software for a specific field is not a good thing. Especially because you *need* an answer to create a tag. But asking nonsensical questions just because you want to introduce the tag is also not a good thing.

If you have a real question about the software now that you are working with it you can simply add the tag by typing it in the tag bar when asking a new question. It would be very nice if you could afterwards propose a tag wiki for the tag so that other users who stumble upon the tag know what it's about.

The best thing would probably be to wait a bit and when there are a couple of questions making a new tag and re-tagging the older questions. This way we would know that the tag would not only be created for one single question.

There currently is one question on the site mentioning articy:draft: [Can Articy Draft be used to write a book?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/8643/23159). So if you have a couple other questions about the software I think it's okay to create the new tag and re-tag that one.

Comment: I feel so stupid now, I didn't even know you could just make your own tag when you ask a question. I always just assumed you have to choose from the available tags... well, I don't have any questions right now, but I'll be sure to ask them as they come up. I hope I wont be the only one relying on articy.

Comment: @noClue No reason to feel stupid. It's good that you asked on Meta before making a new tag. There are all kinds of useless tags that are created regularly, often when people have a typo in the word. These often get deleted automatically after a re-tag. If a tag doesn't have any questions for 30 days or so the system removes it, which is why it would be better to have at least a couple of questions for the tag. It's also a privilege for which you need 150 reputation here and 300 on other sites, so it's not immediately visible that you can create tags this way.